# HipChat API update my own status

Tags: api, hipchat

How can I use the HipChat API to update my own status (Available/Away/Do not disturb)?

I've tried https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/update_user with an access token having all scopes, but I get the message "HipChat Admin can not update Atlassian account user's email".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the update_user API requires that you pass the entire content of the user, not just the status. For your scenario to work, you'd need to do a first call https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/view_user, get all the data, change the status, and then call  https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/update_user with the full payload.